# Implementation of social media login into intelXDK

Tags: cordova, facebook-login, intel-xdk

Currently intelXDK only provides Facebook Login plugin.
Is it possible to implement other social media login in intelXDK?
Appreciate if someone can provide some guidance.

Comment: Could you please mention what "...other social media login..." includes ? Are you talking about, Twitter, LinkedIn, Google+...?

Comment: @shree202 : other social login as you have mentioned in ur comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my colleagues has been working on an OAuth2 login that utilizes the inAppBrowser feature and, therefore, relies solely on standard HTML5. You can find that example here: https://github.com/krisrak/jquery-cordova-oauth2